# Sum all struct members in a generic way

Tags: c++, gcc, c++98

I have a lot of of C struct which represent counters.
Those structs consist of several members of the same type, let's say `uint64_t`. In the program I have several instances of the same struct and in some cases I need to sum all those same struct. I don't want to use `operator+` for this because in future the structs can change and have more or less members and I don't want to always modify the operator as well.

I thought that I could use a `sizeof` and create an array of struct's member type from the struct and then sum the array. I would make an union of that struct and an array. This would solve my problem of not wanting to modify the operator when new member is added or removed, but this would work only while the struct contains only members of the same type.

So maybe there is some generic, template method of doing this, but I'm not that good with templates so I ask you C++ gurus for help.

Example of such struct:

```
struct counter{
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    uint64_t c;
    uint64_t d;
    uint64_t e;
};
```

Comment: Shortly: Traverse the struct as sequence of adjacent memory cells and sum along the way. Use sizeof to determine how many members you have (assuming all are the same size). Some pointers and a loop will do the job.

Comment: A big problem is that the compiler is free to add padding between the members or at the end of the structure. While it's unlikely for the structure you show in the question it's not possible to make it generic for any structure, especially if you start mixing types. You also need to be wary of breaking strict aliasing.

Comment: modifying `operator+` when the struct changes would be the sensible thing to do.

Comment: @Artur We cannot assume a `struct` members as continuous or adjacent memory cells, it might have some padding for alignment.

Comment: The requirements don't make much sense: "create a generic struct with any number of counter variables, all of varying integer sizes". I would strongly suggest changing the requirements instead. Is there any reason why you _must_ have counters of different types?

Comment: @jblixr: I am aware of potential padding in soma cases hence I added "assuming all are the same size". Of course this is not sufficient condition - so I agree with you. I had no time and saw a point in writing detailed answer describing 'padding' nuances.

Comment: Thanks for all the good comments and answers. I ended up with global operator overload as this seems as the safest approach.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I'm aware of strict aliasing and was actually thinking about it, but I don't think that making an union of struct and an array would break it. Please correct me if I think wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best way, but one way to achieve the functionality you need is:

```
/* counter.xh */
COUNTER_MEMBER(uint64_t, a);
COUNTER_MEMBER(uint64_t, b);
COUNTER_MEMBER(uint64_t, c);
COUNTER_MEMBER(uint64_t, d);
COUNTER_MEMBER(uint64_t, e);
```

Then in some header:

```
/* counter.h */

struct counter{
#define COUNTER_MEMBER(TYPE,NAME) TYPE NAME;
    #include "counter.xh"
};
```

Now comes the add function:

```
/* foo.cpp */
uint64_t add_members(const counter &obj) {
  uint64_t sum = 0LLU;
#define COUNTER_MEMBER(TYPE,NAME) sum += obj.NAME;
#include "counter.xh"
  return sum;  /* I hope there was no overflow */
}
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/Q9OzC9)</kbd>

Comment: And this technique is called [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), isn't it?  Or, at least, I think that's one of the names for it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it is called X-macro.

Comment: I accepted this solution, because it seems to me as the most generic and very easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best solution, however it can be a useful method.
If `struct Counter` have more or less members, I change `GetSumOfAll()` function only.

```
struct Counter 
{
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
    uint64_t c;
    uint64_t d;
    uint64_t e;
};
typedef std::vector< Counter > VecCounter;

uint64_t GetSumOfMember( const VecCounter& vec, uint64_t Counter::*member )
{
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    std::for_each( vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&]( const Counter& counter )
    {
        sum += counter.*member;
    });

    return sum;
}

uint64_t GetSumOfAll( const VecCounter& vec )
{
    uint64_t sumA = GetSumOfMember( vec, &Counter::a );
    uint64_t sumB = GetSumOfMember( vec, &Counter::b );
    uint64_t sumC = GetSumOfMember( vec, &Counter::c );
    uint64_t sumD = GetSumOfMember( vec, &Counter::d );
    uint64_t sumE = GetSumOfMember( vec, &Counter::e );

    return sumA + sumB + sumC + sumD + sumE;
}

int main()
{
    VecCounter v{ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } };
    uint64_t sum = GetSumOfAll( v );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before you suggest all this meta programming, I would strongly suggest that you view the disassembly and see what it actually results in. `g++ -std=c++11 -O3` produces a needlessly complicated program for such a simple task.